# Display Wordpress site from subfolder installation

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have Wordpress installed in a subfolder: www.mydomain.com/p/

I want the front page of www.mydomain.com to show the wordpress ( /p/index.php ) frontpage. I don't want a redirect.

I have tried with this in my root .htaccess:

```
Directoryindex index.php /p/index.php
```

Theres is no index.php file in the root, so it uses the Wordpress index.

It works, but with one problem:
It does not update the page on www.mydomain.com but only on /p/index.php

I use the plugin WP Super Cache.

Is there another solution to doing what i want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I want to share the answer I found a while ago:

Go to Wordpress settings -> general settings, set the **WordPress Address (URL) to**:
http://www.example.com/p

Copy index.php to the root folder.

Edit the root index.php so it includes the wp-blog-header.php from the sub folder:

```
require('./p/wp-blog-header.php');
```

The root .htaccess should have this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is you can redirect using htacess but my suggestion

you just have to move your file from  www.example.com/p/ to www.example.com and change links in database

because each links will redirect from www.example.com/p/

You no need to redirect subfolder to main domain plz move the files to main domain. If u using ftp select files and drag into domain path folder like htdocs / www/ or you can move using cpanel

Otherwise

The possible and simple way in htaccss we can redirect main domain into sub domain.

If you want to do the same as you asked plz refer this link I it will help full.

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect

Comment: I dont want to change links or anything, only displaying wordpress index on www.mydomain.com, i still want the installation and anything else to be in /p/ :-)

Comment: Ok. Please try in wordpress admin end settings -> permalink -> and your custom url